# How to get ValueMember value of a DataGridViewComboBox Column for a selected row column in datagridview

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

 var query = from a in db.itemmasters select new { a.ItemName, a.ItemId_Pk };

 combo1.DataSource = query;

 combo1.DisplayMember = "ItemName";

 combo1.ValueMember = "ItemId_Pk";

 combo1.HeaderText = "Item Name";

 dgvBilling.Columns.Add(combo1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `DataGridView` is called `dg`:

`var currId = (int)dg.CurrentRow.Cells["colName"].Value;`

where colName is the name you give to `combo1`.